# javafx: sort TableView by default

Tags: java, sorting, javafx, tableview

I'm developing a small game that has a highscore list displayed by a javafx `TableView`. I've created a subclass `HighscoreTableView extends TableView` which is a `TableView` node that automatically creates the `TableColumns` I need and fills them with data on construction.

I want that table to be sorted by a default column on initialisation. I've added the following code lines:

```
duration.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING);
this.getSortOrder().add(duration);
duration.setSortable(true);
this.sort();
```

where duration is the `TableColumn` that should define the sorting. Of course, it's added to the `TableView`. But when I create a new instance of that `HighscoreTableView`, it remains unsorted by default, until the user clicks on one of the column headers. This is unexpected, since [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240142/sort-tableview-by-certain-column-javafx), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096353/javafx-re-sorting-a-column-in-a-tableview) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250951/javafx-tableview-arrow-for-a-column-sorted-by-default) say it should work that way. Any ideas?

**Further information for reproduction:**
The `HighscoreTableView` class is used by a `HighscoreStage extends Stage` class, which contains a `TabPane` with four Tabs. Each Tab contains a `HighscoreTableView` with different data taken from a static `Data` object. The data model is a class `HighscoreEntry`, an `ObservableList` of them gets added to the `HighscoreTableView`s. My full code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/LukeLR/a2806cb26f7c7bef3a20e0eec14e69c6).

Comment: I believe for the sorting to work the list in the TableView's `items` property must be a `SortedList` with the `comparator` property bound to the one of the TableView. This is presumably the case with the initial value, but you reset it.  Try changing `this.setItems(list.getObservableList());` to `this.getItems().clear;` followed by `this.getItems().addAll(list);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `sort()` before any data is loaded. Instead you should call it each time after adding/changing data to the table view. 
Also you can use [`SortedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html) with appropriate comparator to wrap your original backing list. Than all changes will be automatically propagated to view.