# How to set rules for default sort in TreeTableView in JavaFX?

Tags: java, sorting, javafx, javafx-8, treetableview

I searched on SO, but only found posts regarding sorting `TreeView`, e.g., 
[JavaFX: TableView: Arrow for a column sorted by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19250951/javafx-tableview-arrow-for-a-column-sorted-by-default) and [Javafx: Re-sorting a column in a TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096353/javafx-re-sorting-a-column-in-a-tableview).

Both don't seem to work with my `TreeTableView`.

Also [Oracle's blog post on Tree Table Views](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm) (see Example 15-4: Sorting Mode Settings) does not really help.

I think it should be some combination of

```
row.setSortType(...)
```

and

```
table.setSortMode(...)
```

and

```
table.sort()
```

and

```
table.getSortOrder(). ...
```

and

```
table.getSortPolicy(). ...
```

yet I could not get it working.

What I want to achive:

1. Define columns & add them to the table (Works fine)
2. Set default sort (e.g., sort data by "`valueColumn`" descending) (How?)
3. Set root (Works, but does not get sorted at the moment)